# instanceof negation

Tags: php, instanceof

Which is the correct format for negating instanceof?

```
if ( ! $a instanceof stdClass)
```

or

```
if ( ! ($a instanceof stdClass) )
```

I've convinced myself the latter is correct way, probably after reading a blog article several years ago, but after some command-line tests, they both seem equivalent. *Are* they?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: how about the more explicit `if ( false === $a instanceof Foo )`? Apart from that, there is no question here because the two expressions are easy enough to test on your own.

Comment: @gor - nice [yoda condition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/558021) ;)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Let's read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

> The following table lists the operators in order of precedence, with the highest-precedence ones at the top.[...]

```
Associativity      Operators       Additional Information
================== =============== ======================
non-associative    instanceof      types
right              !               logical
```

So `instanceof` has higher priority, thus both statements are equivalent. Parenthesis are probably used to make it obvious so you don't need to look it up in the documentation.

Comment: + for including operator precedence.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Useful and easy to understand, thus it's easy to remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

> Are they equivalent?

Yes, logically they are equivalent. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14362690/164998) by **Álvaro G. Vicario** provides more detail *why*.

> Which is the correct format for negating instance of?

Of the two, there is an argument that the following is more readable. But there is no single *way*. That's the beauty and curse of PHP.

```
!($a instanceof stdClass)
```